# WordPress new requirement

Tags: wordpress

So the WordPress min requirement is now updated to PHP 7 or greater: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/
I'm not sure why they changed it from 5.6 to 7 just like that! Many hosts don't even have 5.6 PHP update! Is this means WordPress will not function with 5.6 PHP versions?

Thank you!

Comment: switch to a better hosting or get your own vps/server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link in your question contains the answer. PHP 7 is strongly recommended by not currently required (as of Dec 5, 2016 / WordPress 4.6.1).  PHP 5.2.4 and up still work.

> If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with PHP 5.2.4+ and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have reached official End Of Life and as such may expose your site to security vulnerabilities.

https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/